# What do you need **kwargs for in Kivy when you create the __init__(self, **kwargs) method?

Tags: python, oop, kivy, keyword-argument

I asked ChatGPT for the code to implement a Kivy Hangman App and I got the following code.
However, even after extensive research, I don't understand why the **kwargs is necessary in this specific case. Because you don't pass any arguments when instantiating the object.

My question differs from other questions asked in this regard in one obvious point. However, since my question was closed for reasons that were not explained, I guess I will have to explain it again here. I asked why Kivy needs this for its internal work. I could not find a single question about this here. If you found an answer to that, I would be happy if you could maybe link the question. Because I really didn't find an answer in this forum.

In this tutorial from freeCodeCamp ([https://youtu.be/l8Imtec4ReQ]) it was explained that this is necessary for the internal work of Kivy. But why exactly?
Here is the Code:

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random


class HangmanGame(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.word_list = ["python", "java", "ruby", "javascript", "php"]
        self.guess_word = []
        self.secret_word = ""
        self.remaining_guesses = 6
        self.img_path = "img/hangman_{}.png"
        self.create_game_layout()
        self.new_game()

    def create_game_layout(self):
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.image = Image(source=self.img_path.format(0))
        self.word_label = Label(text=" ".join(self.guess_word),
                                font_size="50sp",
                                halign="center",
                                valign="middle")
        self.remaining_guesses_label = Label(text=f"Remaining guesses: {self.remaining_guesses}")
        self.input_label = Label(text="Enter a letter:")
        self.input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.submit_button = Button(text="Submit", on_press=self.check_letter)
        self.add_widget(self.image)
        self.add_widget(self.word_label)
        self.add_widget(self.remaining_guesses_label)
        self.add_widget(self.input_label)
        self.add_widget(self.input)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

    def new_game(self):
        self.secret_word = random.choice(self.word_list)
        self.guess_word = ["_"] * len(self.secret_word)
        self.remaining_guesses = 6
        self.image.source = self.img_path.format(0)
        self.input.text = ""
        self.word_label.text = " ".join(self.guess_word)
        self.remaining_guesses_label.text = f"Remaining guesses: {self.remaining_guesses}"

    def check_letter(self, instance):
        letter = self.input.text
        if letter in self.secret_word:
            for i, c in enumerate(self.secret_word):
                if c == letter:
                    self.guess_word[i] = letter
            if "_" not in self.guess_word:
                self.end_game(True)
        else:
            self.remaining_guesses -= 1
            self.image.source = self.img_path.format(6 - self.remaining_guesses)
            self.remaining_guesses_label.text = f"Remaining guesses: {self.remaining_guesses}"
            if self.remaining_guesses == 0:
                self.end_game(False)
        self.input.text = ""
        self.word_label.text = " ".join(self.guess_word)

    def end_game(self, victory):
        message = "Congratulations, you won!" if victory else f"Sorry, the word was {self.secret_word}."
        self.remaining_guesses_label.text = message
        self.remove_widget(self.input_label)
        self.remove_widget(self.input)
        self.remove_widget(self.submit_button)
        self.add_widget(Button(text="New Game", on_press=self.new_game))


class HangmanApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
        return HangmanGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HangmanApp().run()
```

I tried to solve my problem on my own through every conceivable way. For about a week now I've been asking ChatGPT for help, watching tutorials and even bought an online course to understand object-oriented programming. But nowhere did I get a really good explanation. That's why I decided to ask this question here, hoping that someone could help me.

Comment: Because [`kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) accepts it, and as it is written your `HangmanGame` class constructor is written to pass its `kwargs` to the parent. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394902/) for a generic explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`BoxLayout` *does* accept additional parameters which you *can* pass upon instantiation. See the documentation: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html. Just because you're not passing any arguments to `HangmanGame()` doesn't mean that you couldn't. The `**kwargs` are there so that additional arguments will be passed through to `BoxLayout.__init__`.